# component.get("v.attribute") not getting

Tags: lightning

'I have a list of items, where each item has its own component. In that component, there is an attribute set to the item itself.

When I click a button, an event fires and that event should be given the attribute to send with it.

However, the item is not added in any way shape or form or whatsoever.

**COMPONENT**

```
<aura:component > 
    <aura:attribute name="field" type="SOCoField__c"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="moveFieldDown" type="c:SOCoFieldEvent" />

        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:down" disabled="true" variant="bare" 
            onclick="{!c.moveFieldDown}" size="large" alternativeText="Move down" />

</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    moveFieldDown : function(component, event, helper) {
        var fieldDownEvent = component.getEvent("moveFieldDown");
        fieldDownEvent.setParams({"field" : component.get("v.field") });
        alert("field = " + component.get("{!v.field.Parent_Form__c}"));
        fieldDownEvent.fire();
    },
```

**EVENT**

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" >
    <aura:attribute name="field" type="SOCoField__c" />
</aura:event>
```

The alert allows me to see if the item is added. Each time I try something, it shows as 'field = undefined'.

WHAT IN THE WORLD AM I DOING WRONG?

I've tried (I think) all variations of component.get/find, {!v.attr...} and without {!}, getting the Parent_Form__c inside and outside the component.("v.field") and none of it is working.

Comment: Why is your JavaScript inline? It should be on its own file!

Comment: It is. I will clarify in the post.

Comment: Your alert is wrong, by the way. The `setParams` line looks ok. researching.

Comment: even though both are wrong :P
I tried the setParams way in the alert too, but both fail to work.

Comment: attempted an answer. Either you didn't include all your code here, or you skipped a few steps.

Comment: @SebastianKessel why did you remove your answer?

Comment: Because it was useless. Once I see your full code, I can try to contribute with an answer that actually helps.

Comment: Ah okay. Well, given that I have approximately 10 components, each with a controller and most of them with a helper, that's going to be a lot of code. I am also not sure if I am at all allowed to post the code (even though nobody in my company knows anything about lightning) online... Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Add a 'debugger;' statement to your controller function and use the browser dev console to explore what values are being set.